# Парс через Html Agility Pack

Tags: javascript, c#, html, htmlagilitypack

Требуется спарсить города(сайт и xPath указаны в коде), но парсятся пустые строки(есть только outerhtml = " option value="spb> < /option" " - для питера, но нужен именно полное название - Санкт-Петербург ), как предполагаю, города загружаются через JS, поэтому их при парсе нет. вопрос очевиден: как все-таки спарсить города?

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = web.Load("https://finance.rambler.ru/currencies/exchange-{city.Value}");
        var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/main/section/section/section/section/table/tbody/tr/td/div");
```

ПЫ на сайте outerhtml = "option value="spb">Санкт-Петербург< /option"

Comment: /html/body/div/main/section/section/section/select/option - какой дурак так делает, малейшее изменение в верстке, и пиши пропало. а про аякс не предполагать надо, а юзать devtools и прочие снифферы

Comment: извиняюсь, давно не писал проект, вот код, думал это функция HAP):         var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = web.Load("https://finance.rambler.ru/currencies/exchange");
            var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/main/section/section/section/table/tbody/tr"); Спасибо за замечание

Comment: Так писал, потому что не знаком с DOM и front-end, данный пример нашел на документации HAP, под свои нужны смог изменить, в отличии от "правильного" варианта, буду исправляться

Comment: @FoggyFinder по работе хватает этого долбаного парсинга. бот пишу. уже в глазах мелькают эти все //a[@class='.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://finance.rambler.ru/currencies/exchange/");

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@class='towns standart-selector']//option"))
{
    string cityValue = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
    string cityName = node.NextSibling.InnerText;    
}
```

Вместо `cityValue` и `cityName` записываете/выводите данные туда, куда вам нужно.

Comment: почти одноникнеймцы) спасибо огромное, можете объяснить фундаментальную разницу с     'var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = web.Load(https://finance.rambler.ru/currencies/exchange);
            var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(/html/body/div/main/section/section/section/table/tbody/tr);' Почему в моем случае пустые строки, а в Вашем все есть

Comment: `<tr>` - это строка в таблице, в этой строке есть ячейки `<td>`. При помощи `.NextSibling` в node'е можно перейти на следующий уровень по xPath. Вот получение данных в цикле foreach:

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//section[@class='rates best-rates']//tbody//tr")`

[Результат](http://i.imgur.com/IqZh15V.png)

_Чисто из-за никнейма не мог мимо пройти)_